# Updating to Lubuntu 16.10 mess up with gtk graphic?

Tags: updates, lubuntu, gtk, 16.10, lxde

I have updated from Lubuntu 16.04 to Lubuntu 16.10. Now the GTK elements in graphic are bugged, like LightDM's session menu , nm-applet, transmission-gtk...

[image]
This is Transmission toolbar (in italian) : all elements are near and "flat".

[image] This is GDEBI Package Installer. As you can see the graphic of the elements is messed up.

Some of them, like nm-applet, acts as normal if I use the LXQt Desktop Environment, but on Lubuntu/LXDE they are not going well.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem when I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10. My theme was not GTK3 compatible. Ended up switching to https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme and it works fine.